# Using jq to loop over objects and return an iterated value

Tags: jq, systemd-journald

I have an enteresting TODO that I'd like some eyes on. I'm using `journalctl` to grab system journal entries and output as JSON. `journalctl` outputs as JSON objects separated by a newline.

Here's a sample of a JSON object outputted from journalctl:

```
{ "__CURSOR" : "s=bd3afe956aec45d89cf3939e839c3647;i=3e084;b=6dd8a3060bdb448d848f4694339c6e94;m=5d0fd53a6;t=5c797ae76d38f;x=6cdb742ba83df8f5", "__REALTIME_TIMES
TAMP" : "1626829164613612", "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP" : "24980054950", "_BOOT_ID" : "6dd8a3030bdb446d858f4694337c6e94", "PRIORITY" : "6", "SYSLOG_FACILITY" : "3",
"CODE_FILE" : "../src/core/job.c", "CODE_LINE" : "845", "CODE_FUNC" : 
"job_log_status_message", "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER" : "systemd", "JOB_TYPE" : "start", "JOB_RES
ULT" : "done", "MESSAGE_ID" : "39f53479d3a045ac8e11786248231fbf", "_TRANSPORT" : "journal", "_PID" : "11282", "_UID" : "1162", "_GID" : "1162", "_COMM" : "syste
md", "_EXE" : "/lib/systemd/systemd", "_CMDLINE" : "/lib/systemd/systemd --user", "_CAP_EFFECTIVE" : "0", "_SELINUX_CONTEXT" : "unconfined\n", "_AUDIT_SESSION"
: "974", "_AUDIT_LOGINUID" : "1162", "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/user.slice/user-1162.slice/user@1162.service/init.scope", "_SYSTEMD_OWNER_UID" : "1162", "_SYSTEMD_UN
IT" : "user@1162.service", "_SYSTEMD_USER_UNIT" : "init.scope", "_SYSTEMD_SLICE" : "user-1162.slice", "_SYSTEMD_USER_SLICE" : "-.slice", "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID
" : "1f72568e79c34f14a525f98ce6a151c2", "_MACHINE_ID" : "32c9faf3dd90422881ce03690ebf0015", "_HOSTNAME" : "ip-192-168-22-27", "MESSAGE" : "Listening on port.", "USER_UNIT" : "dirmngr.socket", "USER_INVOCATION_ID" : 
"7c1e914aada947cd80a45d68275751dc", "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP" :
"1626829165607533" }
```

I'm using `--after-cursor` to get a subset of the journal. There is no `--before-cursor` option afaik so I'm trying to find a way to stop at a specific cursor and search the JSON objects between the `first` and `last` cursor.

At the moment I'm using the following snippet (sloppy by my own admission) to search the journal after a cursor and count the objects where a match is found.

```
journalctl -u my-service --after-cursor="$FIRST_CURSOR" -o json | jq -n 'inputs|select(.MESSAGE|test(".*My search string .*")) | jq length | wc -l
```

I'd like to do this more intelligently with possibly an if/else statement but I'm a `jq` novice.

Answer (score 0):

1. A jq-only solution would be:

```
[inputs|select(.MESSAGE|test("My search string")) | length] | length
```

2. Notice there is no need for the initial or final `.*` in the regex
3. For future reference, please follow the "mcve" guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .
   In particular, your JSON got mangled while copying-and-pasting into SO; and an actual example, with expected output, would be appreciated.